# Eric4 Python IDE - autosave and quick script/project start, run

Tags: python, ide

I've got 2 problems with Eric4 IDE.

Can't find an option in preferences to autosave my changed files before running script. It's very annoying that I have to save my file and then run script.

Second problem is running a script. I can't find any button to run a script/project instantly. 'Run Script' button always opens a setting window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get around this, as it seems there is no built in way is to bind a key to save the file (ctrl+s), then run the script (F2), and finally hit enter (to close the settings window and run the code).

Answer (score 2):

This bothered me a lot too, and I know this is 2 years late but it might help some else who comes here looking for this very solution, like I did. Here are the actual answers, ERIC v4.4:

`Press F4 instead of F2.`

The first time you have to use F2 to 'Start' the script, so dismiss the settings window. After that you can use F4 'Restart' and it will run with the settings you chose initially.

The Autosave option is well hidden unfortunately:

`Settings-->Preferences-->Debugger-->General-->!Scroll down to!-->Start Debugging-->Autosave changed scripts`

And you were spot on - these two things do have a huge impact on productivity.

Comment: What about the annoying popup after a script runs, It shows the `... terminated with an exit status 0`